# AndroidMarket - Upload app

Tags: android, google-play

If I upload an app that I've made in Android's marketplace for selling. How much does google/marketplace take in charge for every penny that I make, and I'm living in Sweden, I've heard they take a percent of the pennty too?

Please can someone explain this to me.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Transaction Fees](https://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?&&answer=112622). Each time you sell your application, Google takes 30% of the application price.

Comment: So only 30 % goes away? Do we pay other type of taxes?

Comment: The tax rate depends on your location. See [Specifying tax rates](https://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=138000).

Comment: In Sweden the taxes are 30% when working, will it be the same for the app?

Comment: Your tax rate will apply for every purchase of the app.

Comment: I've med an account now, But I can't find the list of the percent of taxes that my country takes (except for these 30% from Google).

Comment: Sign in to Google Checkout. Go to `Settings > Select which locations you charge tax in > European Union > Sweden`.

Comment: Can't find it, does that option come after you've made the verifiation of your bank account?